# undefined method `valid_options' for nil:NilClass with simple_form and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, simple-form

I have two models, Category and Post.

**Category.rb**

```
class Category
include Mongoid::Document

field :title, :type => String
has_many :posts, :autosave => true, dependent: :destroy

end
```

**Post.rb**

```
class Post
include Mongoid::Document

field :title, :type => String
belongs_to :category
end
```

I'm using **[simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)**

If I write in my post form the next:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
 <%= f.collection_select :category, Category.all, :id, :title, :prompt => "Choose a Category"%>
 <%= f.input :title %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The form does works fine :).

but if I use the next form with simple_form format:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :category, :prompt => "Choose a Category" %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
 <% end %>
```

I get the next error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `valid_options' for nil:NilClass):
```

**How can I fix it?
Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed. Thank you to Carlos Antonio da Silva :D.

you can find the fix in http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-simpleform/browse_thread/thread/f384f0445af8468e or:

```
<%= f.input :category, :collection => Category.all, :prompt => "Choose a Category" %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't work for me (maybe due to my need of checkboxes). THIS works:
= f.association :categories, :collection => Category.all, as: :check_boxes