# mongoid, form builders and relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, simple-form

i'm expecting some troubles with mixing mongoid and simple_form (i think - the same problem is actual for other form builders). I have a small form with relations, something like

```
f.input :author, collection: User.all, as: :select
```

and when i submit form with no author selected i see exception like

```
NoMethodError in ExamplesController#update
undefined method `id' for "":String
```

So sad :( as i see - simple_form submits "" (empty string) but not nil to controller. Of course - i can validate each param from form builder, but i'm not sure that it is good solution. Can you recommend me something?

**UPD** (Models structure):

user.rb

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :examples, :inverse_of => :author
  has_many :examples, :inverse_of => :responsible_person
end
```

example.rb

```
class Example
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

  field :title, type: String
  field :description, type: String

  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :responsible_person, :class_name => "User"

  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :author

  attr_accessible :title, :description, :author, :responsible_person

end
```

Comment: updated with code structure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this problem with direct use author_id and responsible_person_id on form, like this

```
= f.input :author_id, collection: User.all, as: :select
= f.input :responsible_person_id, collection: User.all, as: :select
```

instead of

```
= f.input :author, collection: User.all, as: :select
= f.input :responsible_person, collection: User.all, as: :select
```

Comment: I have the same solution. It's not very clean to work directly with ID but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= f.association :author %>
```

Comment: No - i need to be able to set blank values, i mean - no author or no responsible person in this example

Comment: i have updated try it I think association will pass nil if you submit with blank.

Comment: It causes NoMethodError with message

undefined method `valid_options' for nil:NilClass

Comment: there are some details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452615/undefined-method-valid-options-for-nilnilclass-with-simple-form-and-mongoid